# Cypress changes headers to lazyUpdate

Tags: http-headers, cypress

I'm running Cypress (10.4.0) with an Angular (10.1.6) project and I'm running into an issue with the headers. At some point during a test the headers are moved into something called `lazyUpdate`:

[image]

Which causes an error with `http.js`:

Which crashes the application.

My test is fairly simple:

```js
describe('Login with an custom email-address', () => {
    it('Visits the login page', () => {
        cy.visit('/');
    });

    it('fills in the login form', () => {
        cy.el('inputEmailAddress').type(Cypress.env('EMAIL'));
        cy.el('inputPassword').type(Cypress.env('PASSWORD'));
        cy.el('buttonLogin').click();
        cy.url().should('not.contain', 'login');
    });
});
```

When I use the application myself the headers never change to the `lazyUpdate` headers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that we use some values from local storage to set the headers, but Cypress clears out local storage between tests causing headers to get undefined. Using the `cypress-localstorage-commands` plugin to store and retrieve headers between tests resolved the issue.